# ASP.NET service vs repository layers

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, repository

What is the difference between a service layer and a repository?  I have worked through a lot of demo ASP.NET MVC apps and most of them have just repositories.  And some have a mixture of both.  When do you use just repositories and when do you use services / or both?  The same is true for ASP.NET web apps.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Repositories act just as gateways to your data storage (sql database, xml file etc.) while services usually implement some business rules on your data before sending the data to be saved in the database via a repository.

consider this example:

```
class UserRepository : IUserRepository
{
   public void Create(User userToCreate)
   {
       //update tracking and save to repository
       _userToCreate.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
       _dataContext.AddNew(userToCreate);
   }
}


class UserService : IUserService 
{
   private IUserRepository _repository;

   public UserService(IUserRepository repository)
   {
        _repository = repository;
   }

   public void Create(User createdByUser, User userToCreate)
   {
       //implement some business rules
       if(!createdByUser.HasRights(UserRights.CanCreateNewUser))
           throw new Exception("This user '"+createdByUser.Name+"' does not have the rights to create a new user");

       //update rules auditing
       _userToCreate.CreatedByUserId = createdByUser.Id;

       //save entity to repository
       _repository.Create(userToCreate);
   }
}
```

Then in your Controller action you will use the service directly where all your business rules can be applied. That way you can test you controllers, business rules (services) and persistence (repositories) separately/independently using mocks.

```
    public ActionResult CreateUser(User newUser)
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
           _userService.Create(this.CurrentUser, newUser);
           if(newUser.Id > 0)
               return RedirectToAction("UserCreated");
        }
        return View(newUser);
    }
```

Comment: Will the service layer always have a corresponding method name in the repository?

Comment: Not necessarily. Consider the Repository as a bunch of queries. For example, the repository layer might have **IQueryable<User> GetUsers** but the service layer can have more methods which use only this same query. e.g. **IList<User> GetUsers(int companyId, int pageNo)**, **User FindUser(int companyId, string name)**, **bool HasUsers(companyId)** etc.

Comment: I like the notion that the service layer would handle the business logic thus removing it from the action methods/controllers.  Thanks for the suggestions Tawani.

Comment: You miss te role of services completely. It's not a container for any kind of business logic. Services are used only for business logic which does not belong to a single aggregate, thus need several entities from different repositories to interact. So if your service uses just a single repository then it's a sign that you're just making your domain model anemic.

Comment: @Pein: Good comment but then where should the business logic that deals with one repository aggregate go?

Comment: It should be in a method of the entity that this business rule conceptually belongs to.

Comment: @Pein Adding methods to entities is a very bad idea. static classes (and Extensions) with methods that apply to Interfaces are much better. When you deal with multiple databases and disparate services, you would rather have POCO's. Also, much easier to unit test

Comment: 1. I think you messes up POCO with DTO.

Comment: 2. What you describe fits rather transaction scripts pattern. We are talking about DDD here.

Comment: Placing business logic into Services and anything that handles data access into Repositories seems to be cleaner and easier understood.

Answer (score 13):

A repository typically handles data-access only. A service layer will use a repository, and apply any additional business logic. Think of the repository as a re-usable layer than could be used by anything that wants to access your data. Different apps might have different business rules (that would go in the service layer), but could all use the same repository layer implmentation

Comment: Where would you put your repositories and services?  What is your project structure like?  I have MyProject.BusinessObjects and MyProject.DataObjects.  I currently have my repositories in my MyProject.BusinessObjects.

Comment: i like to put my domain model (entity framework edmx for instance) and repository classes in a separate project MyProject.Data. Usually my services live inside the MVC Web App project, in a /Services folder (but i wouldn't necessarily consider that a best practice - just a personal preference)

Comment: @qntmfred: The data business logic should be in the same project as MyProject.Data, otherwise you'd end up duplicating business logic across the Web Apps that rely on the MyProject.Data project.