# ASP.NET MVC: seperatation of concern for normal/admin user

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I'm going to separate admin and normal user section of my ASP.NET MVC 5.2 project. My admin area and normal user area have much things shared, however privileges and details for each of them is different.

Right now I don't know how to separate admin area and normal user area. I don't know if I should create different project for admin-panel or I just should route admin to different path and use the same controllers? Or should I route to different path and use different views/controllers?

And a side question, is it possible to have real physically separated admin and normal user area in the same ASP.Net MVC solution or not?

Comment: Are you aware of MVC Areas?

Comment: I think the real question is if you use `Areas` how you can avoid pure code duplication if you need the admin panel to look like the normal app + another admin thingies

Comment: @RoyalBg thanks for your notices. seems this is what i'm looking for

Comment: @RoyalBg is it possible to share models on different areas?

Comment: Yes, models are shared. If you extract the business logic to a service layer, you can have "one-liner" controllers calling services in both User and Admin area

Comment: how about building a custom menu provider that checks for privilege and renders the menu, so that the user does not see admin menu options. Since the controller too will check for permissions, if one types url in browser that is not in menu will still get a 404.

Comment: @RoyalBg can you post your comments as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually in applications there are various endpoints using the same business logic. What should we do in this scenario? We can easily copy one endpoint and paste it in another, but once the business case is changed, we'd need to change everywhere in our code.

In favor of separation of concerns, controllers should have "code" logic and another layer should have the "business" logic. E.g. Controllers might define how properties are named, but not how long an username is. An username should be long at least 3 chars no matter which controllers tries to register the user.

All of that operation with entity models to meet the business case requirements should be moved to a separate layer. Usually called Service layer.

That all of your controllers can use any of that services without being aware from the business scenario behind.

A simple example here are two controller actions - one of the - editing your own profile and the other - the administrator editing an arbitrary user profile.

```
[Authorize]
public IActionResult Edit(UserViewModel model) {
    if(model.Id != this.CurrentlyLoggedUser.Id) { 
        return this.RedirectToAction(...);
    }

    var userService = new UserService(); // inject maybe
    userService.EditById(model.Id, model);

    return this.View();
}
```

and the admin action

```
[Authorize("Admin")]
public IActionResult Edit(UserViewModel model) {
    var userService = new UserService(); // inject maybe
    userService.EditById(model.Id, model);

    return this.View();
}
```

The "code" logic here is - create service, invoke the encapsulated edit logic. Also some security reasons the action should take care about - `Authorize` and `Authorize Admin`.

Comment: Do you know any books or references which has this type of information inside it?

Comment: Not at all. There are some kind of discussions and articles by MSDN for this. Take a look at the official repository pattern article http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application and the discussion Repository vs. Service Layer in SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4368134/asp-net-service-vs-repository-layers

Comment: SUMMARY : You should have to use same controllers for both admin and user panels, but you need to authorize it before confirmation. The Views/Routes could be different but It's recommended that controller should remain same for betterment of change control mechanism.